# Why VLC Media Player video lags when I fast forward ts video file?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I download a lot of ts video from website. I've noticed about VLC Media Player playing: video lags for around one to two second when I fast forward the video. Other file types like mp4 work perfectly fine. MKV is a little lags but it's okay. Because of these reasons I look for alternatives apps like Gomplayer and Potplayer - they play without lagging. However I still love VLC. Is there any way fix this with settings?

Comment: XPS 15 9650, Windows 10 build 19043, Intel Core i5 7thGen.